# switching between the page in not working in pagination

Tags: ember.js, pagination

I have used ember-cli-pagination for adding pagination in my ember app.
Pagination is added to the ui but in number it is changing the page number but in ui it is not displayed.

in my controllers i have added:

```
 queryParams: ["page", "perPage"],
  page: 1,
  perPage: 3,
  pagedContent: pagedArray('content', {
    page: Ember.computed.alias("parent.page"),
    perPage: Ember.computed.alias("parent.perPage"),
  }),
  totalPages: Ember.computed.oneWay("pagedContent.totalPages"),
```

in router i have added>>

```
model:function(){
    return this.store.findAll('rule');   
  },
```

how to switch between the pages>>>

Answer (score 0):

The example from [`ember-cli-pagination`](https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination#remote-paginated-api) shows to write the model hook in your Route so you call `this.findPaged`.  You are calling the store to return all records, so you are bypassing the pagination model.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(RouteMixin, {
  // optional. default is 10
  perPage: 25,

  model: function(params) {
    // todo is your model name
    // returns a PagedRemoteArray
    return this.findPaged('todo',params);
  }
});
```

I'm not sure if "how to switch between the pages>>>" is a question, but if you're asking how to switch between pages, you would do that by setting the controller property `page` to the desired value.

Comment: i want for local store??

Comment: `i want for local store??` means what exactly?  Are you trying to say that what I have in my answer works for you, doesn't work for you, or is this a follow-on question about something?

Comment: what happens?  Do you get an error in the console?  Do you get any data at all using `findPaged()`?